# A colorful glass circle

Tags: visual, retrograde-analysis

<sub>Entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #40](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/fortnightly-topic-challenge-40-retrograde-analysis?cb=1)</sub>

You've returned from your lunch break to a small package.  Inside is a note that reads:

> Please come to my office at your earliest convenience.  We have important matters to discuss, assuming you can figure out what the topic of our meeting will be.  All you need to do is figure out how this little present was constructed.
>   - The Boss

Along with the letter is a circular piece of glass with various colors inside.

Front:

[image: top]

Back:

[image: bottom]

What is the topic that will be discussed at this meeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> BONUS, assuming that the word inside is all I have to figure out.

Reasoning:

> Well, B and S are easy to figure out (just remember the S is backwards.) O is also not hard to find, and N (when you look at it from the front you can barely make out.) U, seen from the back, is the same as seen from the front. If you put these in order from front to back, you get BONUS.

Comment: same exact timestamp. nice.

Comment: actually this one is 3 seconds later. But yeah, pretty darn close.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> BONUS. Your boss would like to discuss you receiving a bonus. You figure this out by looking for what letters could make up the different shapes in the overall images.